# Snake sort a 2D array with pointers

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm bad at C pointers, I'm not sure how should I sort the whole array, the code below sorted the array row-wise only, with a warning "assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]". This code sure works in Windows, not sure for other OSes. I am supposed to create a function called snake with 2D const int pointer array, and its size, m as inputs. I am not allowed to move or swap the contents within the array to be scanned, also the whole main function is not allowed to be edited. For example, the input for the whole program is

```
3
9 8 7
5 4 6
3 2 1
```

The correct output should be

```
1 2 3
6 5 4
7 8 9
```

Instead, I got this

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

And here is my code. There is a commented section in snake() because the assert function will fail if I uncomment it. I was trying to reverse the even rows (but the index starts from 0, so you can say odd rows also) after sorting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void snake(const int *ptr_array[100][100], int m){
    int* p =NULL;
    int temp;
    for(int y=0;y<m;y++){
        for(int k=0;k<m-1;k++){
          for(int g=0;g<m-k-1;g++){
            if(*ptr_array[y][g]>*ptr_array[y][g+1]){
              p=(ptr_array[y][g]);
              (ptr_array[y][g])=(ptr_array[y][g+1]);
              (ptr_array[y][g+1]) = p;
          }
      }
  } 
}
// for(int h=1;h<m;h+=2){
//     for(int g=0;g<m/2;g++){
//         p = (ptr_array[h][m-g]);
//         (ptr_array[h][m-g]) = (ptr_array[h][g]);
//         (ptr_array[h][g]) = p;
//     }
// }
}

int main()
{
  int array[100][100], check[100][100];
  const int *ptr_array[100][100];
  int i, j, m;

  scanf("%d", &m);
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      ptr_array[i][j] = &(array[i][j]);
      scanf("%d", &(array[i][j]));
      check[i][j] = array[i][j];
  }
}

snake(ptr_array, m);

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      assert(check[i][j] == array[i][j]);
      assert((ptr_array[i][j] >= &array[0][0]) && (ptr_array[i][j] <= &array[99][99]));
      printf("%d ", *(ptr_array[i][j]));
  }
  printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void snake(const int *ptr_array[100][100], int m){
    int* p =NULL;
    int* w=NULL;
    int temp,l;
    for(int y=0;y<m;y++){
        for(int k=0;k<m;k++){
            p = ptr_array[y][k];
            l = k+1;
            for(int g=y;g<m;g++){
                while(l<m){
                    if(*p>*ptr_array[g][l]){
                        p=(ptr_array[g][l]);
                        (ptr_array[g][l])=(ptr_array[y][k]);
                        (ptr_array[y][k]) = p;
                    }
                    l++;
                }
                l=0;
            }
        } 
    }
    for(int h=1;h<m;h+=2){
        for(int g=0;g<=(m-1)/2;g++){
            w = (ptr_array[h][m-1-g]);
            (ptr_array[h][m-1-g]) = (ptr_array[h][g]);
            (ptr_array[h][g]) = w;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).